# SQL Left Join Query Result Row

Tags: mysql, database, join

When you perform a left join on two tables let's say teacher and department `ON teacher.id = department.id`. Left join will compare each record from the left table (teacher) with each record from the right table (department) and join the record into a result row if the `teacher.id = department.id`.

What happens to the rows from each of the tables when the `teacher.id != department.id`? Do the rows from the teacher and department table still get joined into one result row except each column value for the result row will have a value of `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have 2 tables:

`Table1`

```
tc1
0
1
2
```

and `Table2`

```
tc2
0
2
3
```

This would be the result from the various queries on these 2 tables

```
SELECT tc1, tc2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE tc1=tc2
```

Result:

```
tc1  tc2
0    0
2    2
```

This is the same as this query:

```
SELECT tc1, tc2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON tc1=tc2
```

It basically returns only the rows where tc1=tc2. Simple. Now outer joins behave differently. They include all the rows from one table.
`LEFT` means it will include all the rows from the set that you already have, even if they don't match anything in the joined table.
`RIGHT` means that it will include all rows from the joined table, even if they don't match anything in the rows you already have.
`FULL` will return all the rows from both sides.

When a match is not found on one side, the values are returned as `NULL`

```
SELECT tc1, tc2 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON tc1=tc2
```

the result will be:

```
tc1  tc2
0    0
1    NULL
2    2
```

Now, with right join

```
SELECT tc1, tc2 FROM table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON tc1=tc2
```

will return

```
tc1  tc2
0    0
2    2
NULL 3
```

And now, full outer join

```
SELECT tc1, tc2 FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON tc1=tc2
```

will return all the rows, with matching nulls

```
tc1  tc2
0    0
1    NULL
2    2
NULL 3
```

Keep in mind, that these are equivalent:

```
INNER JOIN        <=>  JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN   <=>  LEFT JOIN
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  <=>  RIGHT JOIN
```

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you for taking the time to explain the examples.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains excellently left and right outer joins, I think you should take a look: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: This post answered my questions 100%. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For a clear explanation on how Left & Right joins work, and the results they may produce, check these:

[Left joins explained.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

[Right joins explained.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp)

Hope it helps.